# how to detect unused imports?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In my code im often adding some import statements like e.g.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

During development some of these import statements may become unnecessary because i move the code that required these imports. In eclipse, unused imports are marked by the IDE, but in Visual Studio 2010 I couldn't find any hint. How can i detected them?

Comment: And if you are interested in why there's no warning for unused usings - here's Eric Lippert's blog post on that topic - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/25/why-are-unused-using-directives-not-a-warning.aspx

Comment: for mac : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43883965/2736039

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Studio has this feature built in if you want to remove them rather than just detect them: [Automatic Code Generation -> Organize usings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx#Anchor_3)

> The Remove Unused Usings option in the Visual Studio user interface removes using directives, using aliases, and extern aliases that are not used in the source code. There are two ways to call the operation:
>
> - Main Menu - On the Edit menu, point to IntelliSense, point to Organize Usings, and then click Remove Unused Usings.
> - Context Menu - Right-click anywhere inside the code editor, point to Organize Usings, and then click Remove Unused Usings.

**Edit to include information from comments**

Franci has chimed in with the Powershell extension to VS 2010 which adds in more functionality to do this task as well as others: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99

Comment: And the PowerCommands extension (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) adds the Remove and Sort command at a solution level as well.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2019 comes with default code cleanup that fixes this. Shortcut is to press CTRL+K and CTRL+E as default.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019

[image]

You can also use the command "Remove and Sort Usings" with CTRL+R and CTRL+G.

[image]