# Sort and remove unused imports in tsx and ts files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I prefer to use Visual Studio as my single IDE and not switch to Visual Studio Code like a lot of my colleagues does for front end development. One thing that I truly miss is [Visual Studio Code `Organize imports`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_organize-imports-for-javascript-and-typescript).

[Is there a way to remove unused imports and declarations from Angular 2+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46722701/3850405)

I can achieve this in C# files for unused `using` namespaces using `default code cleanup` but I have not found anything that does it for `.ts` and `.tsx` files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022243/3850405

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to look twice, you could simply right click and press `Organize Imports`

[image]

Original shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270676/3850405